# Logic to check the number is divisible by 3 or not?

Tags: c, math

without using %, / or * , I have to find the no. is divisible by 3 or not?

it might be an interview question.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean it leaves no reminder? All numbers are divisible by 3.

Comment: @Ash: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/divisible. "divisible" has two meanings, the literal "capable of being divided", and the more specific mathematical meaning. How much would you care to bet that the caller genuinely intends the non-mathematical meaning here, or that he's talking about division in a field as opposed to in the ring of integers? ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subtract 3 until you either

hit 0 - number was divisible by 3 (or)

get a number less than 0 - number wasn't divisible

```
 if (number > 0)
 {
        while (number > 0)
        {
            number -= 3;
    }
}
else if( number < 0)
{
    while number < 0:
        number += 3
}
return number == 0
```

Comment: Also we can shorten the code with first doing `temp_no = (number < 0)? -number : number;` or `number = abs (number);` and then continue with the first loop

Answer (score 11):

There are various ways. The simplest is pretty obvious:

```
int isdivby3(int n) {
    if (n < 0) n = -n;

    while (n > 0) n -= 3;

    return n == 0;
}
```

But we can improve that. Any number can be represented like this: ("," means range inclusive):

```
Base2 (AKA binary)
(0,1) + 2*(0,1) + 4*(0,1)

Base4
(0,3) + 4*(0,3) + 16*(0,3)

BaseN
(0,N-1) + N*(0,N-1) + N*N*(0,N-1)
```

Now the trick is, a number `x` is divisible by `n-1` if and only if the digitsum of `x` in base `n` is divisible by `n-1`. This trick is well-known for 9:

```
1926 = 6 + 2*10 + 9*100 + 1*1000
6+2+9+1 = 8 + 1*10
8+1 = 9 thus 1926 is divisible by 9
```

Now we can apply that for 3 too in base4. And were lucky since 4 is a power of 2 we can do binary bitwise operations. I use the notation `number(base)`.

```
27(10) = 123(4)
Digitsum
12(4)
Digitsum again
3(4) = Divisible!
```

Now let's translate that to C:

```
int div3(int n) {
    if (n < 0) n = -n;
    else if (n == 0) return 1;

    while (n > 3) {
        int d = 0;

        while (n > 0) {
            d += n & 3;
            n >>= 2;
        }

        n = d;
    }

    return n == 3;
}
```

Blazing fast.

Comment: +1 for the second version, although it doesn't work for negative input. Should it, or is it going to be documented valid for non-negative input only?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Good catch on non-negative input. I just got home and I'll work on a tad better version.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Edited my answer with new version and explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a reasonably efficient algorithm for large numbers.  (Well not very efficient, but reasonable given the constraints.)

Use `sprintf` to convert it to a string, convert each digit back to a number.  Add up the digits.  If you come up with 3, 6, or 9, it is divisible by 3.  Anything else less than 10, it is not.  Anything over 9, recurse.

For instance to test the number 813478902 you'd stringify, then add the digits to get 42, add those digits to get 6, so it is divisible by 3.

Comment: I considered putting that answer down but sprintf uses `%` and `/` internally.

Comment: -1 How are you going to stringify a number without `%` and `/`?

Comment: @nightcracker: question says without using those operators, it doesn't say without using standard functions that *presumably* are implemented using those operators, but are not specified to be so. This would be a perfectly reasonable answer in a sub-C compiler that could call the standard libraries, but whose own `%/*` operators were mysteriously broken. +1 to counter -1, I think if the interviewer imposes unrealistic restrictions then they should expect weaselly answers, and should have a follow-up question prepared with more specific restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

just use a for loop subtracting 3 over and over and see if you get to 0. if you get to negative without getting to 0 then you know its not divisible by 3

Answer (score 1):

To print a count sequence which is divisible by 3 without division or modulus operator.

Notice the count sequence:

```
00: 00(00)
01: 0001
02: 0010
03: 00(11)
04: 0100
05: 0101
06: 01(10)
07: 0111
08: 1000
09: 10(01)
10: 1010
11: 1011
12: 11(00)
13: 1101
14: 1110
15: 11(11)
16: 10000
17: 10001
18: 100(10)
19: 10011
20: 10100
21: 101(01)
```

Note that the last two bits of those numbers which are divisible by three (shown in brackets) are cycling through `{00, 11, 10, 01}` . What we need to check is if the last two bits of the count sequence has these bits in a sequence.

First we start matching with `mask = 00` and loop while the first number is not encountered with the lower two bits `00`. When a match is found we then do `(mask + 03) & 0x03` which gets us the next mask in the set. And we continue to match the last two bits of the next count with `11`. Which can be done by `((count & 3) == mask)`

The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int i=0;
  unsigned int mask = 0x00;

  for (i=0; i<100;i++)
  {
    if ((i&0x03) == mask)
    {
      printf ("\n%d", i);
      mask = (mask + 3) & 0x03;
    }
  }
  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This is not a general one. Best is to use the solution which @nightcracker have suggested

Also if you really want to implement the division operation i without using the divide operations. I would tell you to have a look at the Non-Restoring Division Algorithm, this can be done in program with a lot of bit manipulations with bitwise operators. Here are some links and references for it.

[Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29#Non-restoring_division)

[Here is a demo from UMass](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/koren/arith/simulator/NRDiv/)

Also have a look at [Computer Organization by Carl Hamacher, Zvonko Vranesic, Safwat Zaky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072320869)

Answer (score 0):

```
number = abs(number)

while (number > 0)
{
   number -= 3;
}

return number == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose n is the number in question and it is non-negative.

If n is 0 it is divisible by 3; otherwise n = (2^p)*(2*n1+1) and n is divisible by 3 iff 2*n1+1 is, iff there is a k>=0 with 2*n1+1 = 3*(2*k+1) iff n1 = 3*k+1 iff n1=1 or n1> 1 and n1-1 is divisible by 3. So:

```
int ism3( int n)
{   for(;n;)
    {    while( !(n & 1)) n >>= 1;
         n >>= 1;
         if ( n == 0) return 0;
         n-= 1;
    }
    return 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to know if a number is divisible by 3 is to sum all its digits and divide the result by 3. If the sum of the digits is divisible by 3, so the number itself is divisible by 3. For instance, 54467565687 is divisible by 3, because 5+4+4+6+7+5+6+5+6+8+7 = 63, and 63 is divisible by 3. So, no matter how big is the number, you can find if it is divisible by 3 just adding all its digits, and subtracting 3 from the value of this sum until you have a result smaller than 3. If this result is 0, the value of the sum is divisible by 3 (and so the original number), otherwise the sum is not divisible by 3 (and the original number is not divisible, either). It's done much more quickly than subtract 3 successively from the original number (of course, specially if it is a large number) and with no divisions. Um abraço a todos.

Artur

Answer (score 0):

A number is divisible by three if its binary alternating digit sum is zero:

```
bool by3(int n) {
  int s=0;
  for (int q=1; n; s+=q*(n&1), n>>=1, q*=-1);
  return !s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use user feedback:

```
int isDivisibleBy3(int n)
{
   int areDivisibleBy3[] = {};
   for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
   {
       if(n == areDivisibleBy3[i])
       {
           return 1;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

When a user reports a bug stating that a number that is divisble by 3 is not giving the correct result, you simply add that number to the array and increase the number `i` is compared to in the for loop condition.

This is great because then you never have to worry about numbers the user never uses.

Don't forget to add a unit test for whenever a user reports a bug!